# MySQL doesn't start anymore

Tags: mysql, xampp

I can't start up MySQL in XAMPP anymore? Here are the error screen captures. Can some one help me out on this one?

Thanks,

[image]

Here the event Viewer (Sorry I only have screen captures):
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you also check the Windows Event Viewer??

Comment: The part of the log we can see here looks like a normal restart and crash recovery. Are there any more lines below what you show here? It is always a better idea to copy/paste the errors into your question, rather than showing us pictures

Comment: @RiggsFolly : No there are no lines under the last line. The lines you can see are the lines associated to my last attemp of restarting MySQL server

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I updated my question with the captures of the Event logger. Does this help? MySQL seems to try to repair a table for some reason...

Comment: Try [this as suggested on the MySQL forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,652134,652135#msg-652135)

Comment: Have you checked your port and IP settings? I would expect to see a value in the Socket field, from your log output above. has anything changed?